# Determining what is the direction of inclination of movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> In the figure shown in the diagram in front of you, it is given that the angle of inclination of the inclined surface is $30^{\circ },m=2 \text{kg}$ and $M=2\text{kg}$.
> At a certain moment, we release the group from the state of rest. Given that the bobbin is perfect and the thread mass is negligible.
>
> Determine what is the direction of inclination of movement.
>
> [image]

**Here is my solution :**
When the  group is in a state of rest, the result is that :
$$\sum F\:=\:0$$
Which mean that :
$$\boxed{\text{mg} = T}$$
Where $T$ is Thread tensile strength. After releasing the group from a state of rest, it results in:
\begin{align}&\sum F\:=\text{ma} \\
&\text{mg}-T=\text{ma}\\
&\boxed{ \text{mg}>T}\\
\end{align}
Therefore, the inclination of motion is toward the top of the surface

**My question** :
Is my solution right? if yes, Is my solution wrong when the inclination of motion is down the surface? and if no, why?

> The answer given in the book :
> $$\boxed{\text{mg}>\text{Mg}\sin30}$$
> Therefore the net force on the group is toward the top of the inclined plane, so the inclination of motion is toward the top of the inclined plane.
> *Note That I understand why this answer is correct.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my solution right? if yes, Is my solution wrong when the inclination of motion is down the surface? and if no, why?

Yes, your solution is right!!
But it doesn't depend upon the inclination of motion you just need to assume where the acceleration is going to be.
Suppose you assume that the inclination of motion will be down the surface then you will calculate like this or upwards for $m$:
$$ T - mg = ma$$
But since the actual acceleration is upward the incline (or downward for $m$) thus you will get the value of $T-mg$ negative and the acceleration in $Ma$ would be negative (since mass cannot be negative) and thus you would know that the acceleration is in the opposite direction or downwards for $m$.
Thus, in these types of questions, we need to assume the direction of acceleration and if the result is negative the acceleration is in opposite direction.

> The answer given in the book:  $$mg>Mg\sin 30°$$

The reason for this is that $$m = M = 2\text{kg}$$
And since $$\sin(\theta) \leq 1$$ thus
$$mg > Mg\sin 30°$$